# Simple @Modifying - @Query issue Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have loaded up the following query, however for some reason I am getting:

> Validation failed for query for method public abstract void

this happens before i begin the application, if i comment it out it works just fine.

The rest of the query work just fine

The query in question is :

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE user u SET u.name=:name WHERE u.internalId=:internalId")
public  void markEntryAsRead(@Param("internalId") String internalId, @Param("name") String name);
```

Just need to know if the query is done correctly

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error message? Are sure it's `UPDATE user u` and not `UPDATE User u`?

Comment: added error log :)

Comment: @sonic18 so is it working with `Update User u`?   As you can see in your logs, there's `user is not mapped [UPDATE user c SET c.service_type=:service_type WHERE c.msisdn=:msisdn]`. Looks like you have the same error in another `query`. Could you provide the whole `UserRepo` class?

Comment: I tried it with Update User u , the result is still the same. i also uploaded the UserRepo. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `CrudRepository` defined as `CrudRepository<UserModel, String>`?

It should be `CrudRepository<UserModel, Long>` because the `id` of your `UserModel` entity is of type `Long`.

Also, in the query you've presented:

> `@Transactional
>   @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
>   @Query("UPDATE user u SET u.internalId=:internalId WHERE u.id=:id")
>   void markEntryAsRead(@Param("id") String id, @Param("internalId") String   internalId);`

you pass `id` parameter as `String`, but in should be `int`, because in your entity you have `private int id;` Same with `internalId`.

**So**

try to define your `CrudRepository` as `CrudRepository<UserModel, Long>`, and use not `User`, but `UserModel` in your Queries, e.g.:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying //clearAutomatically is true by default, so there's no need to specify it
@Query("UPDATE UserModel u SET u.internalId=:internalId WHERE u.id=:id")
void markEntryAsRead(@Param("id") int id, @Param("internalId") int internalId);

@Transactional
@Modifying //clearAutomatically is true by default, so there's no need to specify it
@Query("UPDATE UserModel u SET u.name=:name WHERE u.internalId=:internalId")
public void markEntryAsRead(@Param("internalId") int internalId, @Param("name") String name);
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

Since you're using `CrudRepository`, you can simply call:

```
UserModel userModel = userRepo.findOne(id);
userModel.setInternalId(internalId);
userRepo.save(userModel);
```

Or, if you aren't selecting by `id`:

```
List<UserModel> userList = userRepo.findByName(internalId);
userList.forEach(user -> user.setName(name));
userRepo.save(userList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The userRepo is :

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<UserModel, String>{

@Transactional
Long internalId(String internalId);


@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE user u SET u.internalId=:internalId WHERE u.id=:id")
void markEntryAsRead(@Param("id") String id, @Param("internalId") String internalId);


}
```

Comment: This should not be the answer. Please, edit your question with this and remove it.